# Getting the datasource of all components inside the page using SPE

Tags: powershell-extensions, components

I'm creating a script that would list down all the components in the a particular page then displays the
RenderingItemName, RenderingItemID, RenderingItemPath, RenderingDatasource, etc.,

I found the script below somewhere in the internet and slightly modify it. The script works for getting the information I need except for the datasource which is always blank.

Please help.

```
write-host 'Running script...'
Set-Location master:\sitecore\content\NL\site1 
$pages = get-item master:\sitecore\content\NL\site1\Splash | get-childitem -Recurse
$device = Get-LayoutDevice -Default
$Results = @();
$DataPath = "C:\Components\ComponentsInUse.csv"     

function Test-DataSourceRequired {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([Sitecore.Data.ID]$RenderingId)

    $rendering = Get-Item master: -ID $RenderingId
    
    # if data source location and data source template are empty then it's ok for the rendering to have no data source defined
    return -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($rendering."Datasource Location") -or -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($rendering."Datasource Template")
}
 
foreach($page in $pages){
 
    $renderings = Get-Rendering -Item $page -Device $device -FinalLayout -Language "nl-nl" | Where-Object { (Test-DataSourceRequired $_.ItemID) }
 
    foreach($rendering in $renderings){
 
        if($rendering.ItemID -ne $null)
        {
            $renderingItem = Get-Item master: -ID $rendering.ItemID
            if($renderingItem -ne $null)
            {
                $Properties = @{
                    RenderingItemName = $renderingItem.Name
                    RenderingItemID = $renderingItem.ID
                    RenderingItemPath = $renderingItem.Paths.Path
                    RenderingDatasource = $renderingItem.Datasource
                    UsedOnPage = $page.Name
                    UsedOnPageID = $page.ID
                    UsedOnPagePath = $page.Paths.Path
                }
 
                $Results += New-Object psobject -Property $Properties
            }
        }
 
    }
}
 
$Results | Select-Object RenderingItemName,RenderingItemID,RenderingItemPath,RenderingDatasource,UsedOnPage,UsedOnPageID,UsedOnPagePath | Export-Csv -notypeinformation -Path $DataPath
 
write-host 'Script ended'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to get Datasource from an item which is retrieved using Get-Item. Instead you should get datasource from Item retrived using `Get-Rendering`

Change this code

```
$Properties = @{
                    RenderingItemName = $renderingItem.Name
                    RenderingItemID = $renderingItem.ID
                    RenderingItemPath = $renderingItem.Paths.Path
                    RenderingDatasource = $renderingItem.Datasource
                    UsedOnPage = $page.Name
                    UsedOnPageID = $page.ID
                    UsedOnPagePath = $page.Paths.Path
                }
```

with

```
$Properties = @{
                    RenderingItemName = $renderingItem.Name
                    RenderingItemID = $renderingItem.ID
                    RenderingItemPath = $renderingItem.Paths.Path
                    RenderingDatasource = $rendering.Datasource
                    UsedOnPage = $page.Name
                    UsedOnPageID = $page.ID
                    UsedOnPagePath = $page.Paths.Path
                }
```

Note that `$renderingItem.Datasource` has been changed with `$rendering.Datasource`